# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '',-2),'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, mysql

```
"select " . TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE . "." . DB_USERTABLE_USERID .
" userid, " . TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE . "." . DB_USERTABLE_NAME .
" username, " . TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE . "." . DB_USERTABLE_NAME .
" link, " . DB_AVATARFIELD .
" avatar,substring_index(substring_index(wp_usermeta.meta_value ,'"',-2),'"',1) role from  " .
TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE .
"left join wp_usermeta on " . TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE .
"." . DB_USERTABLE_USERID .
"= wp_usermeta.user_id  left join cometchat_status on " .
TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE . "." . DB_USERTABLE_USERID .
" = cometchat_status.userid " . DB_AVATARTABLE .
" where (select count(*) from wp_bp_friends where (initiator_user_id='" .
$userid .
"' and friend_user_id=wp_users.ID) or (initiator_user_id=wp_users.ID and friend_user_id='" .
$userid .
"'))=1 and wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' order by username asc"
```

There is an error at substring how do I avoid that.

Comment: That is not a mysql problem. Looks like you use php to get data from mysql database, so add the php tag and more code.

Comment: I recommend that you use a php editor like net-beans or PHPStorm if you can. They show the exact location of these errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this part of the statement:

```
" avatar,substring_index(substring_index(wp_usermeta.meta_value ,'"',-2),'"',1) role from  "
```

You're using `"` to delimit the PHP string, but inside it you're trying to use SQL strings containing `"`. The embedded quote is terminating the PHP string. You need to escape the embedded quotes:

```
" avatar,substring_index(substring_index(wp_usermeta.meta_value ,'\"',-2),'\"',1) role from  "
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `"` double-quotes inside your MySQL statement. These are interpreted by PHP as closing the string, so you need to escape them: `\"`

```
"select ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." userid, ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_NAME." username, ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_NAME." link, ".DB_AVATARFIELD." avatar,substring_index(substring_index(wp_usermeta.meta_value ,'\"',-2),'\"',1) role from  ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE."left join wp_usermeta on ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID."= wp_usermeta.user_id  left join cometchat_status on ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." = cometchat_status.userid ".DB_AVATARTABLE." where (select count(*) from wp_bp_friends where (initiator_user_id='".$userid."' and friend_user_id=wp_users.ID) or (initiator_user_id=wp_users.ID and friend_user_id='".$userid."'))=1 and wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' order by username asc"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape double quotes in this code:

```
"avatar,substring_index(substring_index(wp_usermeta.meta_value ,'"',-2),'"',1) role from "
```

Turn this into:

```
"avatar,substring_index(substring_index(wp_usermeta.meta_value ,'\"',-2),'\"',1) role from "
```

You have another phrase in your code, where you have to escape the double quotes. You have to escape it like this too, look carefully and you will manage to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this part:

```
" avatar,substring_index(substring_index(wp_usermeta.meta_value ,'"',-2),'"',1) role from  " .
```

You have double quotes inside a [double-quoted string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double). Those have to be escaped using a backslash:

```
" avatar,substring_index(substring_index(wp_usermeta.meta_value ,'\"',-2),'\"',1) role from  " .
```

However, when constructing complicated strings like this, I would strongly suggest that you use [Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax to improve readability. It could look something like this:

```
<?php

  $utable = TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE;
  $uid = DB_USERTABLE_USERID;
  $uname = DB_USERTABLE_NAME;
  $atable = DB_AVATARTABLE;
  $afield = DB_AVAYATFIELD;

  echo <<<_
select $utable.$uid
    userid, $utable.$uname
    username, $utable.$uname
    link, $afield
    avatar,substring_index(substring_index(wp_usermeta.meta_value ,'"',-2),'"',1)
role from $utable
left join wp_usermeta on $utable.$uid = wp_usermeta.user_id
left join cometchat_status on $utable.$uid = cometchat_status.userid $atable
where
    (select count(*) from wp_bp_friends
       where (initiator_user_id='$userid' and friend_user_id=wp_users.ID)
          or (initiator_user_id=wp_users.ID and friend_user_id='$userid')
    )=1
    and wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' order by username asc
_;
```

Note that [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) are not expanded inside a [Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) so you have to store them in variables first.

If you like, you can replace the closing identifier (`_`) with something more readable, such as `ENDSQL` or similar.

Comment: Right, the OP should rewrite the mess completely instead of "fixing" it.